# Creating a data frame in R from a list of instances

Tags: r, web-scraping, dataframe

I scraped a list of data from a website and have used the following code to convert it to a list in R. Now that I have converted it into a list with elements I cannot get it into a matrix/data frame as I need.

```
htmlpage5<-read_html("http://www.catholichealthinitiatives.org/landing.cfm?  xyzpdqabc=0&id=39524&action=list&sortby=state&pageNo=4")
chihtml5<-html_nodes(htmlpage5,".info")
chi5<-html_text(chihtml5)


chi27<-strsplit(trimws(chi5), '[\n\r\t]+|(?<![A-Z])\\B(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[a-  z]\\.)\\b(?=[A-Z])', perl = TRUE)
chi27

myfunction<-function(x) { 
  if (length(x)==4) {x <- c(x,"")} 
  else if (length(x)==3) {x <- c(x,"","")}
  return(x)}

 chiapply2 <- sapply(chi27, my function)
 chiapply2
```

When I run this code, chiapply 2 results in the following data.

```
[[24]]
[1] "CHI Health Schuyler" "104 W. 17 St."       "Schuyler, NE 68661"  "P     402.352.2441"      ""                   

[[25]]
[1] "CHI Health St. Elizabeth" "555 South 70th Street"    "Lincoln, NE 68510"            "P 402.219.800"           
[5] "F 402.219.8973"
```

etc...

How can I convert this data into a matrix/data frame so that it can then be converted into a cvs/tsv to report into excel. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is the code I am trying to use:

```
chit2 <- t(chiapply2)
class(chit2)
chit2
```

But I am returning this:

```
     [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]        [,6]        [,7]        [,8]        [,9]        [,10]      
[1,] Character,5 Character,6 Character,5 Character,5 Character,5 Character,5 Character,5 Character,5 Character,5 Character,5
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: So each element in your list is an instance? Not a column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have a list, `x`, of instances like you do:

```
> x = list()
> x[[1]] = c("a", 1, 2)
> x[[2]] = c("b", 1, 2)
> x
[[1]]
[1] "a" "1" "2"

[[2]]
[1] "b" "1" "2"
```

I can turn this into a dataframe as follows:

```
> y <- data.frame(t(as.data.frame(x)), row.names = 1:length(x) )
> y
  X1 X2 X3
1  a  1  2
2  b  1  2
```

So if `chiapply2` is your list:

```
chiapply3 <- data.frame(t(as.data.frame(chiapply2)), row.names = 1:length(chiapply2) )
```

This is likely not the most efficient solution, as it requires two casts to `data.frame`, but it's functional...

Comment: Glad to help! Please mark this the answer if it solved your issue